# The Lying Villages

Tags: logical-deduction

**This isn't a duplicate! The "Two doors with two guards - one lies, one tells the truth" isn't like this question! You just have to pay attention in each one to se the difference.**

> A man was walking along the road on the way to ***Village Where All
>   People Speak Truth***, which is nearby ***Village Where All People
>   Lie***. He had never been to any of the villages so he didn't know the
>   way. He didn't want to go to ***Village Where All People Lie***.
>
> At one point there is a fork in the road and he knows that to one side
>   is the village where he wants to go and to the other side is the
>   village who he wants to avoid at all costs.
>
> Not knowing whether to go to the right or left, gets confused. Then he
>   sees a woman in the middle of the fork. He don't know to which
>   village she lives, then he will only ask ONE question to the woman,
>   and thereby discover the way to the ***Village Where All People Speak
>   Truth***.

What he should ask?

Comment: If there were only one guard in the other puzzle, I would agree this one is a duplicate, but since here there is only one person to ask, the same answer can not serve both puzzles.

Comment: @Dennisdeems: You're only asking one question anyway, so the person you ask it to can't matter.

Comment: @Deusovi but the question you ask in order to solve the two guards problem can not be asked here.

Comment: @dennisdeems: I assume you're talking about the "other guard" question (there's another solution) - that can be changed with the trivial replacement of "someone from the other village".

Comment: This isn't a duplicate! The "Two doors with two guards - one lies, one tells the truth" isn't like this question! You just have to pay attention in each one to se the difference.

Comment: How does the man know she must be from either village?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like this has to be a duplicate, but here goes:

Ask her:

> What direction would you tell me to go if I asked you which path leads to the Village of Truth-Speakers?
> If she's a truther (props to Drake and Josh), she would tell you to take the path to the truth village, so she tells you to take the path to truth village. If she's a liar, she would tell you to take the path to lie village, so she must lie about that and point you to the path to truth village. Either way, go the way she points.

Comment: lol So Quickly! I will make my own VERY VERY HARD Puzzle.....

Comment: That doesn't work. If she is a Truther, she will point to the truth village. If she is a liar, she will point to the Liar village.

Comment: @GordonK not quite - if you just asked "which road leads to the truthers", she'd point you to the liars. But since you're asking what she'd say if you asked that, her *truthful* answer would be the liars, so she'd lie again, pointing you to the truthers and essentially negating her first lie.

Comment: @BaileyM Fair point. I would just ask her where she lived.

Comment: @GordonK that's...yeah, that'd do it.

Comment: I knew there would be a more elegant way. Nice @GordonK

Comment: @GordonK how would asking where she lived solve it?

Comment: @dennisdeems If she is a Truther, she will point towards the village where people always tell the truth. If she is a Liar, she will point towards the village where people always tell the truth. Just go the way that she points,

Comment: Wow, that is elegant indeed.  Would that work with the two guards/two doors problem?  I don't think it would.